# What is the number of fixed plaintexts of RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa, number-theory

Considering RSA, $n=p\,q$ with $p,q$ odd primes and the public key $(n,e)$,  where $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$,  I need a hint on how to show that the number of plaintexts with $E_e(x)=x$ equals  $\gcd(e-1,p-1)\cdot gcd(e-1,q-1)$. So we are searching for the number of plaintexts that remain unchanged by the encryption function using the public key.

Comment: Sights! HW problem!

Comment: Your ego is wrong. It's from a textbook I'm self-studying. Asked for a hint and not a solution, yet here you are bragging about your "homework discovery".  Such behavior is toxic to the community and your karma. Have a nice day stranger.

Comment: it is not ego, it is an inference that the same question occurred twice in the last two days. Happy to hear that you are asking for your self-learning. Here we have a policy about HW problems that we don't answer and only provide hints. Have fun at learning.